# InvalidDefinitionException while creating a custom field type in solr from springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr, jackson-databind

I am trying to create a custom field type in solr from spring boot application. I have employee class which contains Address as a nested object

```
package com.apachesolr.sample.application.model;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.mapping.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.mapping.SolrDocument;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SolrDocument(collection ="Employee" )
public class Employee {

    @Indexed
    private String name;
    @Indexed
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private List<Address> address;
}
```

Here is my Address class:

```
package com.apachesolr.sample.application.model;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexableField;
import org.apache.lucene.search.SortField;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams;
import org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter;
import org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType;
import org.apache.solr.schema.SchemaField;
import org.apache.solr.uninverting.UninvertingReader.Type;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Address extends FieldType {

    public Address() {

    }

    public Address(String fieldTypeName, SolrParams q) {
        super();
    }

    public Address(String fieldTypeName) {
        super();
    }

    private String addressLine;
    private String zipcode;
    private String State;
    private String country;

    @Override
    public Type getUninversionType(SchemaField sf) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(TextResponseWriter writer, String name, IndexableField f) throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    public SortField getSortField(SchemaField field, boolean top) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have added field this field type and a field in schema.xml:

```
 <fieldType name="Address" class="com.apachesolr.sample.application.model.Address" docValues="true"/>
  <field name="address" type="Address"/>
```

But when i tried to index data to employee core using solrCrudRepository it is throwing `InvalidDefinitionException` exception, Please let me know how to solve this.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer$1 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.apachesolr.sample.application.model.Employee["address"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.apachesolr.sample.application.model.Address["indexAnalyzer"]->org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer["reuseStrategy"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1300) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:46) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1518) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1007) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:456) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:183) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at com.apachesolr.sample.application.config.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:75) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
```

tried creating getters and setters but not working

Comment: can you try by removing lombok from your persisting entity? I mean create/add the code at your own

Comment: Removed lombok annotations and created my own getters and setters but still issue exists

Comment: Please add the property SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS= false to your object mapper like objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

Comment: I wanted you to remove all the lombok code and try if ...remove this lombok dependency and try

Comment: here is nice answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70630933/no-serializer-found-problem-returning-responseentity-including-exception

Comment: added configuration as suggested, but now while trying to index data, it getting indexed some other data rather than what it supposed to be. it was supposed to be store 

{
    "name": "xyz",
    "id": "2",
    "address": [{
        "addressLine": "xyz street",
        "zipcode": "12345",
        "state": "AP",
        "country": "India"
    }]
}

Comment: But it is storing

{
    "name": "xyz",
    "id": "2",
    "address": [
        {
            "typeName": null,
            "indexAnalyzer": {
                "reuseStrategy": {},
                "version": {
                    "major": 8,
                    "minor": 11,
                    "bugfix": 2,
                    "prerelease": 0
                }
            },

Comment: "queryAnalyzer": {
                "reuseStrategy": {},
                "version": {
                    "major": 8,
                    "minor": 11,
                    "bugfix": 2,
                    "prerelease": 0
                }
            },

Comment: "similarityFactory": null,
            "similarity": null,
            "postingsFormat": null,
            "docValuesFormat": null,
            "addressLine": "xyz street",
            "zipcode": "12345",
            "country": "India",
            "state": "AP",
            "numberType": null,
            "multiValued": false,
            "explicitQueryAnalyzer": false,
            "explicitAnalyzer": false,
            "tokenized": false,
            "polyField": false,

Comment: "pointField": false,
            "utf8Field": false,
            "classArg": "com.apachesolr.sample.application.model.Address"
        }
    ]
}

@AbhijitBashetti

Comment: May I know why are you extending the address class with FieldType...? public class Address extends FieldType... Can you remove it and try indexing the data again. I hope it would then index the correct and expected data.

Comment: when i edit with this configuration in schema.xml  
<fieldType name="Address" class="com.apachesolr.sample.application.model.Address" docValues="true"/>

  <field name="address" type="Address"/>

I am getting

 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core Employee: Can't load schema C:\solr-8.11.2\solr-8.11.2\server\solr\Employee\conf\myschema.xml: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "Address": Error loading class 'com.apachesolr.sample.application.model.Address'

I am getting this exception, @AbhijitBashetti

Comment: could you please let me know how to configure schema.xml file for custom java classes to add as solr field type.@AbhijitBashetti

Comment: I think it not able to load Address class since i am giving class="com.apachesolr.sample.application.model.Address"(this class is from java code) in schema.xml file. is there any other way that we can give class other than specifying qualified java class name? @AbhijitBashetti

Comment: If you want to add a custom field type in solr, I think you may need to checkout the solr code and then you need add it there and then build jar/war of it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705276/custom-field-class-in-solr?rq=1 ... you can check this